# How should I include Boostrap in Webpack and Angular2 project

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack

I need boostrap in my Angular2 project. The css and the js file. How I must include this in the project to make webpack work?
In the version with systemjs it was included in the index.html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\emersy.css">


<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

How I must do this with webpack? Should I use the vendor.js or something other? Or should I only copy this resources to a asset folder and link this resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in here https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/696
or Create angular applications with webpack based tooling https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check something like this https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader

Also you can include bootstrap and some other libraries (jquery for example) via separate vendor.js. Here is plugin for webpack for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-vendor-chunk-plugin